How to simply distinguish Base<T> and Base<Int> in Derived<Int> during checking C++ code in clang AST?
I'm checking some C++ code pattern via clang AST and run into a problem. Consider following code:
template<typename T>
class Base { };

template<typename T>
class Derived1 : public Base<T>
{ };


template<typename T>
class Derived2 : public Base<int>
{ };

class template Derived1 has a dependent base while Derived2 doesn't. However, if I what I get is the node of an instance like Derived<int>, the base class is now Base<int> and I can't find a convenient way to tell which pattern this base class fits, Derived1 or Derived2?
I know I can always record a base's index in its base sequence, return to derived class's original template node and use the index to find the templated class's base node and see if it is a dependent base. But this way seems quite inconvenient. Is there a more convenient way?
I've tried to find if there's some information in base class's template arguments but right now got nothing useful for this problem.
Thanks a lot for any help.

I think you are asking the following question:

Given that I have a
ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl,
and I then navigate to its
CXXBaseSpecifier,
how can I tell if the base class was dependent in the original
ClassTemplateDecl
by inspecting the template arguments of that base class specifier?

The answer to that question is you call
CXXBaseSpecifier::getType(),
then search within it for a
SubstTemplateTypeParmType.
That type node represents a type that was originally denoted by a
template parameter, but now has been bound to a template argument.
For the code in your example, if you are looking at the
ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl corresponding to Derived1<int>, then
the type of the base is
ElaboratedType, which points to a
TemplateSpecializationType, which has the
SubstTemplateTypeParmType, which is bound to the
BuiltinType for int.
This chain is depicted in the following diagram, with the
SubstTemplateTypeParmType node highlighted in green:

That diagram was made using a tool of mine called
print-clang-ast
that I use for ad-hoc exploration of the Clang AST.  The C++ input was:
template<typename T>
class Base { };

// Dependent base 'Base<T>'.
template<typename T>
class Derived1 : public Base<T>
{ };

Derived1<int> d1;

In contrast, when using Derived2<int> in your original example, there
will not be a SubstTemplateTypeParmType; the template argument will be
BuiltinType directly.
Now, in the case of nested templates, the SubstTemplateTypeParm
could be coming from a different level of nesting than you expect, so
depending on exactly why you're performing this query, you may have to
check the
getAssociatedDecl().
However, having explained how to do it the way I think you want, if I
were writing something to look for specializations of tempates that had
dependent bases, I would simply navigate back to the template and check
its base specifiers.  You've said that is "inconvenient", but to me it
seems more straightforward, and it could well be less code since you can
then use
Type::isDependentType().
But of course I don't know precisely what you're trying to accomplish.
